# SQL Server 2005 show all date in month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I wanna ask about SQL Server 2005 syntax

1) I have problem in select ........
to show date in a month like this :

```
8/1/2016
8/2/2016
8/3/2016
8/4/2016
8/5/2016
8/6/2016
8/7/2016
8/8/2016
.
.
.
.
.
8/31/2016
9/1/2016
```

2) How to select datetime with time format and date.
Example:

```
scan
2016-08-19 07:01:46.000
```

and the result i want from table `scan` is

```
scanDate   | scanTime
2016-08-19 | 07:01:46
```

Comment: On the first part of the question: do you have the Numbers table in the database, or can you add it? On the second - splitting and formatting is best left to the client app.

Comment: i dont have table yet....but i can add one table just for date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To separate `date` and `Time` in two different columns you can use below query.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateColumnName,101) as scanDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateColumnName,108) as scanTime
FROM table
```

Comment: DateColumn column name will be `same` .. either it will be `DateColumn` or `DateColumnName` for both ..

Comment: I am glad it helped. if answer was helpful, you may upvote and set as corret answer :)